# How can i Rewrite File instead of appending using StreamWriter and file stream

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter, file-writing

I want to rewrite text file using `StreamWriter`. but when `StreamWriter` uses stream (like following code), the text will append to file.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fstream);
sw.Write(text);
sw.Close();
```

i must use Stream in code because of that file share limitation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileMode.Create ll create a new file. If the file excists, it ll show exception. Use FileMode.Truncate.

```
 string txt="your text";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\rajesh.kumar\Desktop\test123.txt", FileMode.Truncate))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            writer.Write("txt");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use file stream, set [FileMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        writer.Write(textToAdd);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi.i want to read file before of Writing. then filestream declared with FileMode.Open

Comment: @hosseinsafavi create two different streams - for reading and writing - it's good way